# Eclipse warning me for an option I appear to have

Tags: eclipse, spoofax

I am trying to get up and running with Spoofax.  When I try to run my project, I get the  following warning:

```
Spoofax needs Eclipse to be started with (can be set in eclipse.ini):
-vmargs -server -Xmx1024m -Xss8m 

The following options are currently missing:
-server
```

But here is my eclipse.ini file.  The options appear to be present.  What am I missing?

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server/jvm.dll
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-server
-Xss8m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7.0_45
-Xms40m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

EDIT: This is what I have under Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments:

```
-server -Xss8m -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7.0_45 -Xms40m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Did you try and set them in the debug configuration file of your Spoofax program?

Comment: No, I have no idea what that is . . . trying to get started.

Comment: `eclipse.ini` looks correct. The problem must be elsewhere. What do you do right before you get the error above?

Comment: I hit the "run eclipse application" button at the top of the Eclipse window.  I now see it says "run eclipse application (already running)".  But I don't see any evidence that it is, in fact, running.

Comment: `Run` -> `Run Configurations` -> `Arguments` -> `VM Arguments`

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Spoofax, it does not correctly find the -server parameter. This has been fixed in the unstable/nightly release, but not in the stable version yet.

Answer (score 0):

-X parameter have to be defined before -D otherwise they will be ignored.

at least i figured this out by using the java debug parameters

```
-Xdebug
-Xnoagent
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4144
```

If i place these parameters after the first -D statement they will be ignored.